# Change lable text in uitablecell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement tablecell in which there is one label with text = 0 and two button  with text '+' and '-'

- when i click + button then i want to increment text label by one.
- when i click - button then i want to decrement text label by one.

Any idea how to change the label of uitablecell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have the buttons already in the cell? Or do you also need to know how to add a button to a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier{
    UIButton * mp;
    UILabel *l1;  
    UITableViewCell *cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60) reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];  
    l1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 15.0, 400.0, 40.0)];  
    l1.tag=1;  
    l1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic" size:17];  
    l1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];  
    l1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];  
    l1.numberOfLines=3;  
    [cell.contentView addSubview:l1];  
    [l1 release]; 

mp=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 25, 50, 20)];
mp.tag=2;
mp.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
mp.textColor=[UIColor blueColor ];
[mp addTarget:self  action:@selector(mapbtnpressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:mp];
[mp release] 
        return cell;  
}
```

in a cellForRowAtIndexPath method u call

```
cell=[self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];  
labelname=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];  

    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelname];  

click event  
+  
    labelname.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[lanename.text intvalue]+1];    
-event   
  labelname.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[lanename.text intvalue]-1];
```

Comment: I have also put two button in UITablecell view. You have mention only one label on the cell. How to put two button also.

Comment: you have to declare button in getcellcontentview

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setText:` method of `UILabel`

```
[urLabel setText:newText];

- (IBAction)plusButtonPressed
{
int value = [urLabel.text intValue];
value++;
[urLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value]];
}
```

Comment: How to get that label text first if it is pressed for three time then i have change the from 0 to 3. so, how can i get label text first.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) of documentation. Especially, **Listing 5-3**. The basic idea is that all custom subviews should be added to `contentView` of your table cell.

Comment: Hello thanks, But i didn't get it. so, please provide me example code for that.